# Strange characters when using Google Fonts on some systems

Tags: html, character-encoding, google-font-api

This is an issue I can't recreate on all Operating systems or browsers but only on some. In out office, 2 of the 6 computer show deranged characters.

We are using the Google Web Font Amaranth.  http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Amaranth

See pic pls. (left is good, right is bad)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be any of the following things, Can you check / change to be consistent:

If you switch off CSS, do you still see the same behavior?

Whats the browser encoding on the machines / browsers where you see the problem vs where you don't?

What doctype and meta tags are you using?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
It's on all browser on two Windows 7 machines. 1 is 64 bit. the other is 32 bit.

Comment: that tells me its an OS level thing, not necessarily a browser thing.

Comment: but what would make an OS render them like that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it’s the local font manager, (font being activated in font explorer for example)
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108645